# Why field _created_by is not included when using $guarded in laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel

When using `Model::create();`, why `_created_by` field is the only field that is not included when using `protected $guarded = [];`?

But when I use `$fillable`, it works perfectly fine.

P.S. I'm using laravel 10

Comment: Does the field name really having that leading `_` in it?

Comment: Eloquent will check if a field starts with `_` and consider it not fillable if it isn't explicitly defined as fillable

Comment: @ceejayoz yes it starts with underscore

Comment: @lagbox can you share the reference for this?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4247b594924bc84ec37c5b0a9f0feb92d3de299b/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php#L189

Comment: @lagbox please add your answer, so I can mark it as asnwer

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent treats fields starting with `_` to be 'protected' in a way. These fields are excluded from being fillable unless they are explicitly set as 'fillable' on the Model.

You would have to add this field to the `$fillable` array on the Model for it to become fillable.

[Laravel Framework 10.x - Github - Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\GuardsAttributes @ `isFillable`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4247b594924bc84ec37c5b0a9f0feb92d3de299b/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/GuardsAttributes.php#L189)